# APF and iptables on router - dissallow SSH on specific subnet host

Tags: linux, iptables, subnet

I have a CentOS router with APF installed.

1 terminal with 3 NICs (3 IPs) is using that router as a Gateway to access the internet.

What I want is APF to block SSH access, on the 2 of 3 NICs (IPs).
So SSH is only accessible for a specific IP and not all three.

How can I achieve that directly on the router with APF or iptables?

Answer (score 0):

Edit iptables to allow SSH connections from IP 111.222.222.222 and deny from all others.

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Add

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 111.222.222.222 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Comment: No I do not want to block FROM. I want to block TO specific IP of the subnet

Comment: If want the server to be accessible only to the eth1 network. Edit /etc/named.conf with listen-on { 111.222.222.222; };